# HTML page dissimilarity when screen resolution/size changed

Tags: html, css

I have problem in rescaling my page according to the screen. I am doing coding in my laptop, where it seems ok, But when I open this page on desktop with wider screen it doesn't look nice.

```
    div.fullWidth {
        width:100%; 
        height:100%; 
}
```

This is what I am trying in my CSS file, but it is also not working.

Comment: please narrow down your problem description (or in your case, enlarge it) and try to reproduce in a jsFiddle. Also, please explain "not working"...

Comment: What do you mean by **not working**?

Comment: Please provide link to full page. Also, normally pages use whole browser width unless you've set it a fixed widht somewhere.

Comment: this question makes no sense. do you want to scale a whole website with just one div? because that's not possible

Answer (score 0):

Use **CSS3** and stay trouble free :

```
div
{
 resize:both;
 overflow:auto;
}
```

**(or) without CSS3**

Just drop you width and :

```
body{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need all this stuff? 100% width is a normal page's behavior, you don't need extra styles.

Comment: Because for some unknown reason the 100% width concept din't work for me. so just go with this solution. "Why" and "how" will discuss later. Purpose should be solved first. :)

Answer (score 0):

`height: 100%` will not work, try using `100vh`

```
div.fullWidth {
    width:100%; 
    height:100vh; 
}
```

Browser support [here](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)

Comment: It's almost unsupported, I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: That's the most untrue thing I've read in a while, did you see the table? It's supported in all modern browsers with Opera Mini being the exception.

Comment: Actually, yeah, I did. It's buggy or unsupported on most versions of mobile devices, it's not supported on IE8, which is the last supported version of IE on XP, and even on Chrome and Firefox it's supported only on quite recent versions. And most important - you can achieve 100%x100% page size without this stuff.

Comment: Of course you can, however this is what the future is going to be and it's good to start learning/using it now.

Answer (score 0):

if you create an adaptive design that will help you bootstrap framework, but if you create a fixed design is the main wrapper is necessary to specify the width like this

```
<div class="fullWidth"></div>



.fullWidth {
  display: block;
      background: #ddd;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 500px;
      width: 100%;
       min-width: 960px;
}
```